# Issue: Event Of rangeSelectoButton is triggered on graph load even if the rangeSelector Button is not clicked

Tags: highcharts

I am facing a weird issue while using highstocks with stocktools. On My graph load my aftersetExtreme method is triggered with an event of 'rangeSelectorButton', even though the rangeSelectorButton is not clicked. This is breaking my code as I am making an async call on click of the rangeSelectorButton. So if it will hit aftersetExtreme in case of graph load and with no provocation whatsoever, my graph will not load.
Below is my after set extreme Method and some relevant chartoptions.

```
    function afterSetExtremes(e) {        
            if (e.trigger === 'zoom' || e.trigger === 'rangeSelectorButton' || e.trigger === 'navigator') {
               
                props.onZoom(e.min, e.max);
            }
        }


  xAxis: {
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: "%e. %b"
            },
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: afterSetExtremes
            },
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: '#002451'
                }
            },
            lineColor: '#002451',
            lineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                text: `Time`,
                style: {
                    color: '#002451',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            type: 'datetime'
        },



rangeSelector: {
            buttons: zoomButtons,
            inputEnabled: false,
            selected: 6  
        },
        navigator: {
            enabled: true,
            adaptToUpdatedData: false,
            series: {
                data: props.navigatorData[0]
            },
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: '#002451'
                    },
                }
            }
        },
        scrollbar: {
            liveRedraw: false
        },
        stockTools: {
            gui: {
                buttons:['measure','zoomChange','toggleAnnotations'],
                definitions: {
                    measure: {
                        items: ['measureX']
                    },
                    zoomChange:{
                        items:['zoomX']
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: Can any one from highcharts forum help me here? My problem is whenever my graph is loading , aftersetExtremes is triggered with an event of rangeSelectorButton. This should not happen as this event should be triggered only when the rangeSelectorbutton is Clicked.

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor with the sample data? Without the code, it's hard to say what could have an impact on it.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question with some relevant part of my code.Please understand that reproducing it in JS fiddle with exact same scenario will be very difficult.

Comment: I understand that reproducing the issue requires a lot of work, but without it, I and other users are not able to debug your issue and find out the solution. The shared part of the code doesn't say anything without the rest of the config. You don't have to share the whole application, just a simple reproduction of the issue with the sample/dummy data.